# 3D touch implement pop without peek

Tags: ios, objective-c, 3dtouch

I want to use 3D touch to navigate to a menu like in the contacts app or apple music. I have created a custom view controller for this however I don't want to use

```
-(UIViewController *)previewingContext:(id)previewingContext viewControllerForLocation:(CGPoint)location;
```

because the buttons won't be available to click until I pop into the ViewController.

I guess the alternative is to use

```
-(void)previewInteraction:(UIPreviewInteraction *)previewInteraction didUpdatePreviewTransition:(CGFloat)transitionProgress ended:(BOOL)ended
```

and navigate to the ViewController when I get the ended parameter is true.
However I am unsure how to create the blurring and scaling effects manually.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. First off you say you want to create "a context menu" but then you say "I want to use the actions in the view UIViewController I create straight away. In effect I want to pop straight away without peeking."  Effectively you're saying you want to transition directly to the new `UIViewController` without the _Peek menu_.  Can you clarify this… because it's sounding like you just want a custom transition triggered by a 3D Touch…

Comment: Context menu is the wrong wording. I have a UIViewController that I will navigate to once I get true for the ended parameter in 

    -(void)previewInteraction:(UIPreviewInteraction *)previewInteraction didUpdatePreviewTransition:(CGFloat)transitionProgress ended:(BOOL)ended

    However I want the effect of blurring everything but the selected cell that you would usually get when implementing

    -(UIViewController *)previewingContext:(id)previewingContext viewControllerForLocation:(CGPoint)location;

Comment: edit your question to include this additional detail - other SO users may miss it in the comments

Comment: Just a thought ~ in normal peek and pop, e.g. Safari links, there are two levels of force to transition from the peek view to the final view presented in the pop. What you're planning to do could be confusing for users and may be conflict with the [HIG](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/user-interaction/3d-touch/). As you've surmised I think you will need to create a custom transition and probably use the `UITouch` framework to create you own _peek_ that actually works like a **pop**.

Comment: It does seem to conflict with the guidelines but would it be confusing for users though if they have seen it on apple's own apps before, Contacts and music.

Comment: Those are just peeks with custom views… from [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/Adopting3DTouchOniPhone/3DTouchAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016543-CH4-SW1) _"You can optionally configure a preview view controller to include a set of peek quick actions, or deep links into your app. A user can obtain peek quick actions by swiping a peek upward."_